# Auto complete tag like Stack Overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

What is the idea behind implementing a tagging system like Stack Overflow? This is a question for the front-end implementation of it. What are some libraries that are available out there that will allow me to create a front-end tagging system with auto-complete and tag separator like the one Stack Overflow/pivotal tracker uses?

Comment: Have a look at this jQuery Plugin: http://www.iog3.com/322/so_tag-tagging-system-based-on-stackoverflows-tag-search/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery UI autocomplete is a good start. Here is the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) on using multiple values with it. I've used this plugin in several projects for a variety of purposes, including a tagging UI.

Of course, you need a handler to receive the selected values, but that's pretty trivial with AJAX. Your question was about front-end implementation, so I assume you have your back-end data structures covered.

Comment: If that can help anyone passing around here in 2021, the first link on "Here is an example" no longer works, the second link on "documentation" is the only one that matters today.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

seems like a good start, it allows autocomplete by using hardcoded or ajax options(various other cool options too), not to mention almost all the front-end nice stuff